# ASIO: Buffer Loss

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, asio

#### Introduction

I am creating a *Multichannel ASIO Audio and Video* recorder for dance competitions. The video and audio streams must be perfectly synchronized. The main obstacle is that I don’t have access to the real device ([Steinberg UR44](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/audio_interfaces/ur_series/models/ur44.html)) so I work with *ASIO4ALL* while my client with the device just sends logs to me.

## Issue

With *ASIO4ALL* on my machine I have ideal synchronization but the client with the device has a delay growing with time. So here is how I’ve detected buffer loss: the log shows `2482` calls of `AsioOut.AudioAvailable` event handler; recording session duration is `35.133` seconds; buffer size: `512`; format: `16 bit PCM, 44kHz, 1 channel`.

Hence: `35.133 x 44100 / 512 = 3026` calls were to happen in theory but the client had only `2482` so he lost `~20%` of audio data. That’s why the output audio file has only `28.003` seconds of duration (`~20%` smaller than recording session duration) and that’s why the growing with time delay appears in audio-video synchronization.

**Question:** Are this calculation and conclusions correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important that the code handling the buffer callback executes as quickly as possible. If it's doing too much work or running on a slow computer there is a chance that some buffers will get dropped.